# 多頭飼いオーナーさんのaibo連携アプリ認証時の仕様について

Tags: aibo-developer

＞aiboデベロッパーサポート担当さま

連携アプリのOAuth認証の流れで、連携を許可するために「SONY IDでログイン」した際の動きについて質問です。

私自身、保有しているaiboが1匹なので、連携を許可するログイン前後で「aibo選択」のような画面は出てこず、そのまま連携が完了するのですが、ログインした方が多頭飼いの場合は「aibo選択」のような画面は表示されますか？

A)「aibo選択」画面が表示され、リダイレクトしてきた際に取得できる情報（deviceID）はその許可された1匹だけ入ってくる。
もしくは
B)「aibo選択」画面は表示されない。ログイン後にリダイレクトしてきた際に取得できる情報（deviceIDなど）から、デベロッパー側で「どのaiboを許可しますか？」みたいな「aibo選択」機能を実装しないといけない。
それとも
C)「aibo選択」画面は表示されない。多頭飼いの場合は全aiboが連携アプリを許可したことになる。デベロッパー側でDBに個体情報を保存する際も全aiboを登録してOK。
のどれでしょうか？

※デベロッパー側ログイン後にリダイレクトしてきた際に取得できる情報「access_token」や「refresh_token」は「aiboごと」ではなく「SONY IDごと＝オーナーごと」ですから、「C」かと思っているのですが。。

実際にはイベントを検知したaiboのdeviceIDがイベント通知されますので個体識別可能ですが、多頭飼いオーナーさんの「SONY ID認証＝連携アプリと連携時」の仕様を教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

> 連携アプリのOAuth認証の流れで、連携を許可するために「SONY IDでログイン」した際の動きについて質問です。
> 私自身、保有しているaiboが1匹なので、連携を許可するログイン前後で「aibo選択」のような画面は出てこず、そのまま連携が完了するのですが、ログインした方が多頭飼いの場合は「aibo選択」のような画面は表示されますか？

記載していただいている A / B / C の中で、**C の “「aibo選択」画面は表示されない。多頭飼いの場合は全aiboが連携アプリを許可したことになる。”  が現時点での仕様**となります。

連携を許可したオーナーの方が多頭飼いされている場合、
どの aibo を連携アプリと連携させるのかをオーナーさまに選択していただく場合は、
そのような機能および UI を連携アプリで実装していただきますようお願いいたします。

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム